# How do I write an install.script.php file to install multiple components, modules and plugins

Tags: php, development

I have a bunch of modules, plugins, components and media files etc that I want to install in one go to Joomla sites. I know about the XML file way of doing this. Which I have a version that works fine.

But I would also like to be able to enable all of them and set the settings as I would need them, they are usually the same pretty much. 
I just can't seem to find any good documentation that runs through the process.

Would I need to write a huge installation script to search for all of the separate install scripts for each plugin/module or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to, just use built-in feature: package
https://docs.joomla.org/Package

Comment: I have done this way before but I have found there isn't much flexibility with it. I want to be able to send media files to certain folders at the same time. And enable plugins and some other stuff. Can I do all of that from a package?

Comment: yes, sure - you can do it all with proper use of standard tools: place media file - set destination in XML or copy them with script.php of corresponding component; use install or update sql in plugin to enable or disable it and much more. Just keep in mind that package doesn't just copying files - it installs each entry with executing sqls and install script.php files.